# In python why wont my variables change when i try to change them?

Tags: python

Im a python beginner and am creating a rock paper scissors based game, when i try to use my fuctions that should change the variable it wont change it. The fuctions are the only things not working.

I tried to make a function that would create a input that the player could write into and it would set the variable ot that, i also attempted to make the computer choose a random one. (i have random imported). Here is the code

```
def getcomputerchoice():
    choices = ['rock','paper','scissors']
    compchoice = random.choice(choices)
#this function gets the players choice
def getchoiceuser():
    while True:
        print("Your health is  ")
        print(playerhealth)
        print("now choose, rock paper or scissors")
        userchoice = input().strip().lower()
        if userchoice in ['rock','paper','scissors']:
            return userchoice
        else:
            print("Invalid input! Choose rock paper or scissors")
```

Those were for getting the variable. userchoice and compchoice are what arent changing. i set them at the start of the code to 4 and 5 because another piece of code wasnt working without it.

```
#this is used to check whoever wins the round
def checkwinner():
    global health
    if userchoice == compchoice:
        return "Its a tie!"
    elif(
        (userchoice == "rock" and compchoice == "paper") or
        (userchoice == "scissors" and compchoice == "rock") or
        (userchoice == "paper" and compchoice == "scissors")
    ):
        playerhealth -= 10
        print("You lost 10 health from losing!")
    else:
         computerhealth -= 10
         print("WOW!!!!!! Your so good you won and computer lost 10 health!")
that is the code that needed the variables to be set earlier, if something is wrong please tell me.
```